# Salesforce SFDX deploy source from visual studio code to organization error

Tags: visual-studio-code, deployment, salesforce

That Error occurs when deploy source code from visual studio code to my organization.

```
Starting SFDX: Deploy Source to Org

sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath ../../ --json --loglevel fatal

sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath ../../ --json --loglevel fatal

Error: read ECONNRESET
```

It not always meet that error, but very often.
How to fix it.
I read and found some idea about reason, like because my internet problem. But don't know how to fix it.

Comment: As suggested, ECONNRESET mostly arises due to internet issues. If you are trying to deploy a large source to the org, be sure to have a good internet connection during upload.

Comment: No, It's not a large source. Just a file it's wrong too.